# Backbone view script error

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

Why am I getting a script error in this?

Initially what I wanted to ask was about passing a custom variable during a view initialization, but I came down to this.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sachid/cjwd39av/) for this

```js
var ddd = Backbone.View.extend({
  el: "#sd",
  initialize: function() {
    console.log("rrr");
  },
  render: function() {

  }
});


console.log("dd");
var t = new ddd();
console.log(t);
```

```html
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.1.7/underscore-min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/backbone.js/1.3.3/backbone-min.js"></script>

<div id="sd">
  <p id="eee">

  </p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to pass custom variables to your backbone view just do like this.

**in your view initialize**

```
initialize: function(options){
    this.err= options.err;
},
```

And when you are making new instance of your view, just pass your variables as arguments like this

**making new View instance**

```
var err = 'somthing';
var t = new ddd({err: err})
```

**Fixed version**

your code should look like this

```
<html>
<head> 
    <script   src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.8.3/underscore-min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/backbone.js/1.3.3/backbone-min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="sd">
        <p id="eee">

        </p>
    </div>
    <script>
        var PN = Backbone.View.extend({
            el: $('#sd'),
            initialize: function(options) {
                    this.eee = options.eee
            },
            render: function() {
                 console.log(this.eee);
                    return this;
            }
        });

        var v = new PN({eee: 'somthing'});
        v.render();
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: As a best practice, I've found that referencing the variables as `this.options.err` is best. Once you re-assign it to `this.err` it becomes difficult to tell where the variable came from... especially as the code grows over time.

Comment: @Cory Denielson Yes it is the best way, but someone who dont know how to pass custome veribles to view initialization it will be hard to understand.

Comment: I get it. But why am I getting the script error in the run snippet?

Comment: @SachiDangalla can you provide jsfidll

Comment: @SachiDangalla first of all update underscore. And use my answer structure. Your html page must look like this.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using 1.1.7 version of underscore.js which is older. Backbone 1.3.3 is using higher version of underscore.js. because backbone has a dependency to underscore.js . Hope this helps

```js
var ddd = Backbone.View.extend({
  el: "#sd",
  initialize: function() {
    console.log("rrr");
  },
  render: function() {

  }
});


console.log("dd");
var t = new ddd();
console.log(t);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.8.3/underscore-min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/backbone.js/1.3.3/backbone-min.js"></script>

<div id="sd">
  <p id="eee">

  </p>
</div>
```